# cv::LUT() - what is the interpolation argument?

Tags: c++, opencv

```
 void LUT(InputArray src, InputArray lut, OutputArray dst, int interpolation=0 )
```

makes a substitution in a 8-bit array, according to a look-up table, and stores the result in dst.

The opencv [official documentation on the function](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/core/doc/operations_on_arrays.html#lut) is silent on the `interpolation` parameter. What is it used for and what values can be passed for it?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It seems to be redundant (or maybe reserved for some future expansion).

If you look at the implementation of that function, this is what you'll see (note the assertion in the second line of the function body!) :

```
void cv::LUT( InputArray _src, InputArray _lut, OutputArray _dst, int interpolation )
{
    Mat src = _src.getMat(), lut = _lut.getMat();
    CV_Assert( interpolation == 0 );
    int cn = src.channels();
    int lutcn = lut.channels();

    CV_Assert( (lutcn == cn || lutcn == 1) &&
        lut.total() == 256 && lut.isContinuous() &&
        (src.depth() == CV_8U || src.depth() == CV_8S) );
    _dst.create( src.dims, src.size, CV_MAKETYPE(lut.depth(), cn));
    Mat dst = _dst.getMat();

    LUTFunc func = lutTab[lut.depth()];
    CV_Assert( func != 0 );

    const Mat* arrays[] = {&src, &dst, 0};
    uchar* ptrs[2];
    NAryMatIterator it(arrays, ptrs);
    int len = (int)it.size;

    for( size_t i = 0; i < it.nplanes; i++, ++it )
        func(ptrs[0], lut.data, ptrs[1], len, cn, lutcn);
}
```